# Why do i get some errors in File input output code in java?

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors

```
    package newcode;

    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.File;

    public class File {
        public static void main(String [] args){
            File file =new File("FileName.txt");
```

This above line shows an error "The constructor File(String) is undefined"

```
            try{
            if(!file.exists()){
```

This above line shows an error "The method exists() is undefined for the type File"

```
                file.createNewFile();
            }
```

This above line shows an error "The method createNewFile() is undefined for the type File"

```
            PrintWriter pw= PrintWriter(file);
```

Error after above line"The method PrintWriter(File) is undefined for the type File"

```
            pw.println("File text started here:");
            }
            catch(IOException e){// here error shows
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: that is because you created a File class, and when you say new File(...) it thinks you mean the class you're working in. rename your class, or use the complete path of java.io.File

Comment: And NB the `exists()/createNewFile()` stuff is a complete waste of time and space. `new PrintWriter()` already does all that. You are forcing it to happen twice, along with a deletion of the file you just so pointlessly created. You are also missing the keyword `new`.

Comment: That import shoud not work at all. You should receive an error saying something like `File is already defined in this compilation unit` or from an IDE something about `The import java.io.File conflicts with a type defined in the same file`.

Comment: I got it ! 
Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your class.
When you instantiated File class it thinks you are refering to your own class.